# Is there a statistics library for PHP?

Tags: php, statistics, libraries

I need to find a polynomial regression line, and I'm using PHP - is there a library or 3rd part script that will do this for me? If it can do ANOVA as well that would be a bonus, but mainly, I need to find regression lines.

I don't know how to calculate a polynomial trend line, and I suspect it would be too difficult for me to learn how to do it myself, so if someone else has a script I'd like to use it. I would also be willing to use another program, that can be called from php (so command line only - no gui) but I would prefer to stick to php.

Comment: There's a trend library built into PHPExcel that includes a polynomial best fit class (as well as linear, logarithmic, exponential and power trends). That might give you a starting point.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.phpclasses.org/ ?

Comment: There is a stats extension, but I'm not sure if it will do what you need  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would also be willing to use
> another program, that can be called
> from php (so command line only - no
> gui) but I would prefer to stick to
> php.

I call [R](http://www.r-project.org/) from my PHP webpages. [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) is required. Once you've got R set up you can call your R scripts from PHP via [`curl()`](https://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: Do you have an example? RCurl appears to retrieve things over HTTP. How do you use it serve the results from R in a manner that makes them retrievable from PHP?

Comment: @Rikki: Have your R script return a JSON object to your PHP script.  Then you can do as you like with the object. For larger amounts of data, have your R script write its output to a temporary text file. Return the url of that file to your PHP script.

Comment: but how do you execute the R script? On a cronjob? exec()?

Comment: @Rikki This should help http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/

Comment: @JohnGalt: that's what I was expecting. I don't see how that uses RCurl and does not "call your R scripts from PHP via curl()" (because it's via exec()). The answer is misleading, without an example.

Comment: @Rikki: you may need to use RApache (http://rapache.net/) as well. We've got ours set up so it only accepts calls from localhost which helps with security.  My sysadmin set that up so I can't really tell you much more about it.