# Numeric pattern detection in php

Tags: php, design-patterns, detection

I'm working on pattern detection of data in PHP. The data consists of timeseries with an interval of 1 minute and a value (integer). Now I'm trying to detect patterns in it, e.g.

- Every 10 minutes there's a spike.
- Every 7th day of the week there's a drop.
- Every day between 10pm and 6am there's low traffic.
- ...

Does anyone have a clue how to manage to do this, and where to start?

Thank you in advance!

JSON sample data (take a look at the "data" array):

```
{"data":[5,4,4,3,4,12,4,4,4,3,6,4,3,4,4,10,4,4,3,4,6,3,4,4,3,10,4,3,4,4,5,4,4,3,4,11,3,4,4,3,6,4,3,6,4,9,4,4,3,8,6,3,4,4,3,8,4,2,4,8],"trend":[29.111667641538,27.867587040805],"start":"10-08-2012 09:55","stop":"10-08-2012 10:55"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do pattern detection is through statistical analysis - this allows you to express your pattern as a mathematical model, and the statistical analysis tool looks at the data to see if that model is matched.

The daddy in open source stats tools is R - and it's [possible to call this from PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118232/is-there-a-statistics-library-for-php)

Comment: The keyword in our application is dynamic. How can I realize a dynamic detection without expressing the models myself?